# Joining a .csv and a vector layer in QGIS

Tags: csv, shapefile, qgis

I have a couple of layers that I need to join in QGIS. One of them is a vector one and contains the information about the geometry (a series of polygons, each one characterized by a certain id). On the other side I have a .csv file in which there is information about these polygons, but it is not a single data per polygon, here my problem with the joins. It is a temporal dataset file in which a field appears with a value assigned for each date and polygon (not continuously, but almost).

An example of the .csv file would be:

| id | polygon | date | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 01-01 | 100 |
| 2 | A2 | 01-01 | 500 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 100 | A1 | 02-01 | 250 |
| 101 | A2 | 02-01 | 360 |
| 102 | A3 | 02-01 | 150 |

The idea of joining both files is to be able to make each polygon to be painted (with the help of the "temporal" tool) depending on whether it exceeds a certain value of the cost field.

I have tried to make a relation from "project" but I could only access the form.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Follow solutions works for me.

Add Delimited Text with right data types (our csv).
Vector general -> join attribute by field value. Choose the Join type "Create separate features for each matching feature.